# I need to use an SQL query to return results for the logged in user of my website

Tags: php, mysql

I created a module that will allow my users to view only the categories of blogs that they have selected. I am using an SQL query to access their data from mysqli. The code that I have is working as far as it is properly connecting to mysqli, but it is returning the blog category for everyone, even the users that have not selected the blog category.

How do I specify this code to only access the data from the specific user that is logged into their homepage.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("*****", "****", "*****", "******");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$moduleart = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'ArtsARRA');

$sqlarts = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE      '%MINIARTS%'");

 if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlarts));

else {
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($moduleart);
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the current logged-in user information, use the `$user = JFactory::getUser();` method. More info here - http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, I've been studying that link you added too. But where in my current code would I use the $user variable to get the mysqli query for that specific user?